# how to display categories in store front in magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm a opencart developer,but now i'm going to do project using magento.
i installed magento 1.9.1 version and added new categories in admin panel but it doesnot display in store front...please help me how to do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In admin panel `categories -> manage categories`, click to `default category` then click to `Add Subcategory`. [img](http://prnt.sc/dpotoj)

Give the name to category, set `Is Active` and `Include in Navigation Menu` to yes. Then you can assign product's to the category.

Refresh the cache.

Answer (score 1):

1- Go to admin

2- Catalog->manage categories

3- Select Default category and then add subcategory . You will
remember that subcategory should be created under default category.
Otherwise category will not be visible in frontend.